# Can you please show me how to fix this "ValueError: not enough values to unpack" in beautiful soup?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am going through the Beautiful Soup page of this book
Python for Secret Agents by Steven Lott Dec 11, 2015 2nd edition

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdR6D.jpg

I ran the code from the page and got this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python35\Draft 1.py", line 12, in 
    timestamp_tag, *forecast_list = strong_list
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 1, got 0)

For the life of me I cannot figure out the correct way to fix the code listed here in its entirety:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
query= "http://forecast.weather.gov/shmrn.php?mz=amz117&syn=amz101"
with urllib.request.urlopen(query) as amz117:
    document= BeautifulSoup(amz117.read())

content= document.body.find('div', id='content').div

synopsis = content.contents[4]
forecast = content.contents[5]
strong_list = list(forecast.findAll('strong'))
timestamp_tag, *forecast_list = strong_list

for strong in forecast_list:
    desc= strong.string.strip()
    print( desc, strong.nextSibling.string.strip() )
```

Thanks a million.

Comment: At a guess: the actual data from the URL has changed between when the book was written and now. The error message shows you what's wrong: there is no occurrence of "strong" in `forecast`.

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing the [differences between parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers). And, since you have not provided one explicitly, `BeautifulSoup` picked one automatically based on internal ranking and what you have installed in the Python environment - I suspect, in your case, it picked up `lxml` or `html5lib`. Switch to `html.parser`:

```
document = BeautifulSoup(amz117.read(), "html.parser")
```